# Blue highlight on onclick on buttons in chrome mobile?

Tags: html, css

When I click on a button in mobile chrome. A blue color appears for few a second. How do I remove it? I want to style something of my own like a ripple effect. I couldn't find any pseudo class attached to it in inspect tool.

[image]

```
*:focus {
      outline: none;
      -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
      touch-action: manipulation;
}


div.filterButton{ 
      position: relative;
      padding-top: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
      overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Tried with active, focus.

Comment: put the code here

Comment: Please post the relevant css

Comment: https://developers.google.com/search/ click on hamburger and then on links in mobile phone. You will come to know what I am talking about.

Comment: we are asking what code have you tried so far. Share the code here

Comment: See the code. That's it. I am trying that on button, div, image. Same effect.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It's `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` default behaviour.

```
*:focus {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
a:active {color: red }
```

Comment: It's an animation which appears for a second only. I believe a:active will focus and make color of link red and won't go unitl we click somewhere else on the screen.